# In landscape mode frame setting not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, frame

In iOS 7, When I navigate to a view in landscape mode, frame setting not working. But when I change the orientation, it is working as expected. Why it is behaving so? friends, any suggestion? It is working fine in iOS 6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably happened because you try to set frame in wrong method. If you use this method

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

}
```

Your frame should be respond to any orientation change.